# Record from Web Cam in Java

Tags: java, webcam, jmf, xuggle

I need to record from a webcam. I however have twoadditional requirements. It cant be JMF and it has to be under LGPL or similar license.

Ive checked out Xuggler, but dont know if you can actually record from it. Plus it looks like some parts of it are released under the GPL license. If you have used Xuggler for web cam recording, some details would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with VLCj API and it works great. You need to have the VLC DLLs configured or simply VLC player installed. There is a webcam example in the VLCj code. Google it and you will find the cam capture file which records both audio and video.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [OpenIMAJ](http://sourceforge.net/p/openimaj/home/OpenIMAJ/) or [WebcamCapture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture), both are released on liberal licenses, but you will have to encode `BufferedImage` objects into the stream (e.g. to MJPEG).

Just a note for VLCj - it is not able to discover devices on Windows, so if you decide to use it you will end up with providing webcam locators manually.